# RegSetValueEx no puedo crear una regla en registro usando QT

Tags: c++, windows

Hola estoy usando `RegSetValueEx` para crear mi regla en registro usando Qt cuando uso codeblocks me funciona pero cuando la creo con Qt me da un problema de conversión el codigo es el siguiente:

```
string subclave="Hello";
string valor="Anyone";
LPCTSTR _subclave = TEXT("");
LPCTSTR _valor = TEXT("");
long crear = RegSetValueEx(key, _subclave, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE) _valor, strlen(_valor) * sizeof(char));
```

Errores que obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente hacer la conversión pero cuando lo hago me escribe en chino. El codigo cuando hago las modificaciones que me pide:

```
string hola="hola";
std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(hola.begin(), hola.end());
LPCWSTR subclave = stemp.c_str();
const char * valor = "hola";
long crear = RegSetValueEx(key, subclave, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE) valor,     strlen(valor) * sizeof(char));
```

Captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahí no estás utilizando `Qt` sino, en tal caso, `QtCreator` que no es más que un IDE para C++ especializado para desarrollar con `Qt`. `Qt` no es más que un framework de C++ y tu no estás haciendo uso de ninguna característica propia de `Qt`, al menos no en el código que muestras. De hecho si te funciona en codeblocks es, como podrás ver a continuación, puro azar (tienes un 50% de posibilidades de que funcione).

```
long crear = RegSetValueEx(key, _subclave, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE) _valor, strlen(_valor) * sizeof(char));
```

`strlen(_valor)`: `_valor` no es de tipo `const char*` sino `LPCTSTR`. `LPCTSTR` es un alias cuyo tipo concreto es variable:

- `const char*` si no está declarado `_UNICODE`.
- `const wchar_t*` si está declarado `_UNICODE`.

Dado que la implementación de `strlen` es siempre fija `size_t strlen(const char*)` queda claro que llamar directamente a esta función puede ser motivo de conflictos.

Hay una función, llamada `_tcslen` que te debería servir para este caso... y olvídate de eso de multiplicar por `sizeof(char)`... no te va a solucionar el problema:

```
long crear = RegSetValueEx(key, _subclave, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE) _valor, _tcslen(_valor));
```